# fancy header on bibliography first page

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, fancyhdr

[image]I have used a different first page for all my chapters in my thesis which are defined using:

```
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{3cm}{0.5cm}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\filleft}{\scalebox{5}{\color{gray}\Huge\thechapter}}{2cm}{\Huge}
```

I want my bibliography section to be no different, but I cannot get my fancy header to show up properly on the first page of this section. I think this is a complete MWE for this problem

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\filleft}{\huge\thechapter}{15pt}{\huge}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead[L]{Text here}
    \fancyhead[R]{\slshape \leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{3cm}{0.5cm}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\filleft}{\scalebox{5}{\color{gray}\Huge\thechapter}}{2cm}{\Huge}

    \begin{document}
    \chapter{1}
    some text \cite{reference1}
    \chapter{References}\thispagestyle{empty}
    \hrulefill\\
    \clearpage

    \renewcommand{\bibname}{}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{-3cm}{0.5cm}
    \small
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \bibliography{IEEEfull,library} 

    \end{document}
```

I hope someone can help

Cheers

Comment: I cannot compile your example: "! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \titlespacing"

Comment: Woops - forgot the titlesex package. Apologies

Comment: And the graphicx and xcolor packages as well…

Comment: I managed to compile your example, but I'm not sure what of what you want. Both titles looks really similar to me. Maybee a snapshot, a non-empty bibliography or some further explanations could help ?

Comment: Hey Clément, I've added an image, you can see there is no fancy header on the first page of the references section. This is what I am trying to get. The fancy header shows on the second and subsequent pages

*EDIT I've managed to get a part of the header to work by using \renewcommand{\bibname}{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}
This doesn't print the chapter name in the right header though

Comment: ok, the fact that the bibliography was empty made it hard to understand. You should add a (dummy) library.bib using the [filecontents](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) package.

Comment: Should I edit the original post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*New solution*
It is probably best to redefine the `\bib@heading` command of `scrrpt` to do the formatting for you.  By default the main work is done by simpy `\chapter*{\bibname}` you can replace this with your styling:

```
\chapter{\bibname}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\hrulefill\clearpage
```

by putting the following in your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\bib@heading{%
  \ifbib@leveldown
    \section*{\bibname}%
    \ifx\@mkboth\@gobble\else\markright{\MakeMarkcase{\bibname}}\fi
  \else
  \chapter{\bibname}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \hrulefill\clearpage
  % 
    \@mkboth{\MakeMarkcase{\bibname}}{\MakeMarkcase{\bibname}}%
  \fi
}%
\makeatother
```

You can then issue the `\small` command in the hook `\AfterBibliographyPreamble` and redefine the `bibname` to References via:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\AfterBibliographyPreamble{\small}
```

Putting this together your get:

[image: Revised sample]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\filleft}{\huge\thechapter}{15pt}{\huge}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{Text here}
\fancyhead[R]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{3cm}{0.5cm}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\filleft}{\scalebox{5}{\color{gray}\Huge\thechapter}}{2cm}{\Huge}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\bib@heading{%
  \ifbib@leveldown
    \section*{\bibname}%
    \ifx\@mkboth\@gobble\else\markright{\MakeMarkcase{\bibname}}\fi
  \else
  \chapter{\bibname}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \hrulefill\clearpage
  % 
    \@mkboth{\MakeMarkcase{\bibname}}{\MakeMarkcase{\bibname}}%
  \fi
}%
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\AfterBibliographyPreamble{\small}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}

\nocite{*}
\lipsum[1-20]

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEfull,xampl} 

\end{document}
```

*Original solution*
As you are using `scrrpt` there is a convenient hook `\AfterBibliographyPreamble` you can use, in this case, to specify the page style for this first page and to give the name of the running header.

[image: Sample outut]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\filleft}{\huge\thechapter}{15pt}{\huge}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{Text here}
\fancyhead[R]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{3cm}{0.5cm}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\filleft}{\scalebox{5}{\color{gray}\Huge\thechapter}}{2cm}{\Huge}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}

\nocite{*}
\lipsum[1-20]

\chapter{References}\thispagestyle{empty}
\hrulefill\\

\clearpage

\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{-3cm}{0.5cm}
\small
\AfterBibliographyPreamble{\thispagestyle{fancy}\markboth{REFERENCES}{REFERENCES}}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEfull,xampl} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great Andrew, thank you. 1 small problem though, the chapter name (References) doesn't show up in the right hand header. Any ideas? I've quickly tried using \chaptermark{References}, but this doesn't work

Comment: Updated: just use `\markboth`...